# EditText height slightly changes when it has a border background and maxLines attribute

Tags: android, android-edittext

I implemented an EditText with a customized background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#456891" />
    <corners android:radius="6dp" />
</shape>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_text"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_bg"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

This EditText can show up to 2 lines only. When I entered the third line of text, I noticed that the height of EditText changed a little bit. And this happens only when I add a new line from the second line.

Anyone knows why this happens?

Answer (score 2):

Yes

```
   android:lines="2" //You are missing this attribute.
   android:maxLines="2"
```

After that, your edit text will be 2 lines tall, and no more than 2 lines.